# Python error while attempt to start another process after tkinter app loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to start a new process after main tkinter window is loaded.

*I do it like This:*

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainFrame()
    print(("App loaded"))
    canvasWindow = app.getCurrentTopFrame().start()
    app.mainloop()
    print("Window change")
```

after tkinter init i call function to start new thread

```
  def start(self):
            print("Before logic thread init")
            lock = mp.Lock()
            pro = mp.Process(target = self.manager.startTraining, args = (deley,lock))
            pro.start()
```

This is startTrening fun

```
    def startTraining(self,lock):
    """Starts training sequence"""
        print("start tra")
        for x in range(0,self.numOfGenerations):
            print("x")
            self.population.nextGeneration()
            print("Iteration num ",x,"Fitness of best one is 
            ",self.population.bestSalesman)
            lock.acquire()
 ...........self.canvas.updateFrame(self.population.bestSalesman.dna.getAsListOfTuple())
            lock.release()
```

This is updateFrame fun

```
def updateFrame(self,listOfPoints):
    self.canvas.delete("all")
    for y in listOfPoints:
         self.canvas.create_oval(y[0], y[1], y[0]+5, y[1]+5, fill="Black")
    li = cycle(listOfPoints)
    p2 = next(li)
    for x in listOfPoints:
        p1,p2 = p2, next(li)
        self.canvas.create_line(p1[0],p1[1],p2[0]+2,p2[1]+2)
        if p2 == listOfPoints[-1]:
            self.canvas.create_line(p2[0],p2[1],listOfPoints[0]+2,listOfPoints[0][1]+2)
    self.canvas.pack()
```

I dont get why but behavior is such that main window does load and the 
error occure

```
After init
After tkrasie
after start
App loaded
Before logic thread init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\git\WarsawSchoolOfAI\GeneticsAlgorithms\MainFrame.py", line 129, in <module>
    canvasWindow = app.getCurrentTopFrame().start()
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\git\WarsawSchoolOfAI\GeneticsAlgorithms\MainFrame.py", line 111, in start
    pro.start()
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: *"TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects"*: You **can't** spread `tkinter` widgets across `processes`.